# With PHP and MySQL, how do I properly write smart quotes to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, unicode-normalization, cleditor

I have a PHP website with the [CLEditor richtext control](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) on it. When I try to write Euros and British Pounds to the database, the character goes through just fine because I have the charset set to UTF-8 in the containing page HTML, in the richtext control IFRAME HTML, and in the MySQL table collation. All is well on that front. However, when I try to write [smart quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs), I end up seeing this output in the database:

```
This is a â€œtestâ€.
```

(If that doesn't show up properly above in you browser, the test word has something like a Latin a, a Euro symbol, and the small AE symbol in front of the word, and a Latin a and a Euro symbol after it.)

When I use PHP to read that value back out of the database to display it on the page, it ends up as black diamonds with question marks on them as well as some other Latin characters.

What should I be doing to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure your MySQL table is using UTF-8 as its encoding. If it is, it will look like this:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE Users (
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Next, make sure your HTML page is set to display UTF-8:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    ....
</html>
```

Then it should work.

---

EDIT: I purposefully did not talk about collation, because I thought it was already considered, but for the benefit of everyone, let me add some more to this answer.

You state,

> I have the charset set to UTF-8 … in the MySQL table collation.

## Table collation is not the same thing as charset.

Collation is the act of automagically trying to convert one charset to another **FOR THE PURPOSES OF QUERYING**. E.g., if you have a charset of latin1 and a collation of UTF-8, and you do something like SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE '%—%'; (UTF-8 U+2014) on a table with a charset of latin1 that match either L+0151 *or* U+2014.

Not so coincidentally... if you were output this latin1 encoded character onto a UTF-8 encoded web page, you will get the following:

> This is a â€œtestâ€.

That seems to be the output of your problem, exactly.   Here's the HTML to duplicate it:

```
<?php
$string = "This is a “test”.";
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><?php echo $string; ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Make sure you save this file in latin1...

To see what charset your table is set to, run this query:

```
SELECT CCSA.character_set_name, TABLE_COLLATION FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T,
       information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` CCSA
WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation
  AND T.table_schema = "database"
  AND T.table_name = "table";
```

The *only* proper results for your uses (unless you're using multiple non-English languages) is:

```
+--------------------+-----------------+
| character_set_name | TABLE_COLLATION |
+--------------------+-----------------+
| utf8               | utf8_general_ci |
+--------------------+-----------------+
```

Thanks for the upvotes ;-)

Comment: Not to be curt, because I do appreciate your highly intelligent responses, Theodore -- you've helped me out on some PHP OOP questions in the past with excellent answers. However, to respond here -- been there, done that. I mentioned that already in my post. Note that most other UTF-8 stuff already works. It's just the smart quotes that are acting funky.

Comment: I honestly didn't see where you said you tried the above. I've reread it and still can't see where you mentioned this ;/ I showed you what is commonly the problem. The 3rd step is to check your input characters. But I figured you'd already thought of that one. Guess I was wrong.

Comment: "When I try to write Euros and British Pounds to the database, the character goes through just fine because I have the charset set to UTF-8 in the containing page HTML, in the richtext control IFRAME HTML, and in the MySQL table collation. All is well on that front."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your PHP file has this at the top before any content is printed. I can take latin_swedish_ci into a utf8 encoded website and it encodes correctly.

`header("Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");`

I also put this after my database connection (not sure if this matters as much):

`mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");`

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth for anyone else coming accross this post, I found that adding these mysqld configuration lines - if you have access to the mysql server and can make changes - solved my problem with the curly-quotes.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-server.html

```
# Force UTF8 Charset Encoding
skip-character-set-client-handshake
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
```

I had double-checked the SQL being called from PHP (which appeared fine), and also manually executed an insert/update statment with curly quotes from my GUI (which worked fine), but from the web server was still getting the multi-control characters inserted into the database.

I checked my mysql server variables and noticed latin1 was the default for the server, and the database (even though the table/columns were UTF8). Once I added the lines above and refreshed the page that issued the update statement, the curly quotes did insert correctly.  I can only assume this had something to do with our server's default charset being latin1 and the web server mysql library handshake negotiating as such.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, solve the two following problems first:

- Convert your database to UTF-8.
- Send UTF-8 HTTP headers.

If you are having problems with `â€œtestâ€` in the command-line ***STILL***, after converting the DB, then make sure to run this in your SSH linux CLI before running `mysql`...

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```